# How to pass file in HttpWebRequest Header

Tags: .net-core, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to pass a file in a request header without any success I was wondering do something like this:  request.Headers.Add("file", MyFile);

'I already tried to convert from bytes to string and the file does not post in the request some one have any idea.

Comment: You can't pass a *file* in a header. Headers are meant to sent limited information about a request. What are you trying to do? Why not use POST or PUT to send the file to the server? BTW in .NET Core `HttpWebRequest` uses HttpClient underneath. It's essentially a legacy wrapper

Comment: I'm trying to pass a certificate to validate my request @PanagiotisKanavos